# Applying suggestion-source constraints for typeahead in Marklogic

Tags: xquery, autosuggest, marklogic

Say, I have 5 documents that belong to either of different collections such as:

```
Biography, Fiction, Humour, Adventure
```

For instance, document 1 is in **Adventure** Collection:

```
<Book>
<title>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</title>
<Author>J.K.Rowling</Author>
<year>2007</year>
</Book>
```

document 2, is in **Biography** Collection:

```
<Book>
<title>Steve Jobs</title>
<Author>Walter Issacson</Author>
<year>2011</year>
</Book>
```

Now I want to apply suggest on `year` element. I want to apply this on collections i.e. for example-suggest on Biography collections
I have defined element range index on `year` and ingested sample documents using application loader and configured collections for documents in document settings.

Follwing is my XQUERY code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $options := 
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
 <constraint name="Group">
    <collection prefix="Biography/"/>
 </constraint>

 <suggestion-source ref="Group">
   <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" 
          type="xs:string" >
      <element name="year"/>
   </range>
 </suggestion-source>
 </options>
return    
search:suggest("Group:20", $options)
```

On running this query I am getting suggestions for both *2011* and *2007* which is not what I am expecting.
Expected suggestion is *2011* (as only `Biography` collection should be searched).
I have refered [this doc](http://docs.marklogic.com/search%3asuggest#options) on search:suggest but I am not able to find out what exactly is the mistake.
Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, I am able to achieve the required output using `additional-query` in options as follows:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy"; 
let $options := 
    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        <additional-query>{cts:collection-query("Biography")}
        </additional-query>
        <constraint name="Search_Element">
          <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" 
           type="xs:string" >
            <element name="year"/>
          </range>
        </constraint> 
        <suggestion-source ref="Search_Element">
          <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" 
          type="xs:string" >
          <element name="year"/>
          </range>
        </suggestion-source>
    </options>
return    
search:suggest("Search_Element:20", $options)
```

Still, I was wondering how could it be done without using additional-query paramater because it would be more optimized to use collection constraint for above.

Answer (score 3):

Shrey:

The values from the suggestion source are substituted for the values from the referenced constraint.  In other words, the options say that input qualified by the group constraint should come from the year range index, which is what you're seeing.  For more detail, please see:

```
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_40748
```

To filter a set of suggestions, you can call search:suggest() with two string queries. The first provides the input for the suggestions.  The second provides the filtering constraint.  In the case above, the filtering constraint would be the Biography collection.  For more detail, please see:

```
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_91911
```

Hoping that helps

Comment: Biography is the collection name to which document belongs. Adding another query as search:suggest (("Group:20","Biography"), $options) returns an empty sequence. my problem is that i want to get suggestions on documents from a particular collection on a particular range element. Here biography is the collection and year is element.I went through the links but could not understand properly, could you elaborate right xquery for this